# "justify-content:space-between" for spans

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to layout two spans inside a div in such a way, that all unused space goes between them. Here is the example of what I want to achieve:
[image]

I know that something similar can be achieved using flexbox property `justify-content: space-between;`, but it doesn't seem to work for spans: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexarg/g3rw97er/).

I also tried `text-align` and `float` properties, but couldn't find a way to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not using "inline-block" display and padding/margin for left span?

Comment: @PayamSh Both left and right text have variable widths. I can use margin/padding to put them apart, but won't be able to "stick" them to left and right end of the container. LMK if I misunderstood what you're suggesting.

Comment: Basically no. `flexbox` lays out **blocks**.and blocks are rectangular. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: use display:flex - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pknjr4sw/ or http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0efcow66/

Comment: @Dmitriy your suggestion doesn't seem to work for multi-line spans: http://jsfiddle.net/pknjr4sw/1/

Comment: maybe so? http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/nstvm611/

Comment: @Dmitriy sorry that doesn't work either. Your solution lays spans out as blocks, when I want them to wrap on the edge of the div only. Please see the example image to understand better what I want to achieve.